# How Can I Disable Security In WCF Service And Client Configuration Files

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I'm currently trying to convert some old .NET Remoting code to WCF. I'm not very experienced with either technology and struggling to understand how to configure the service and client configuration files.

I have been working with the WCF Test Client and Service Configuration Utility and I am able to connect a client to the service via `wsHttpBinding`. However, this only works on my local machine because I haven't configured the security yet. Admittedly, I do not currently know how to do this so.

I'd like to modify the configuration files below to temporarily disable security for learning purposes until I fully understand how to configure security. Can someone offer suggestions on what I need to do in order to turn off security in the service and client configuration files below?

Service configuration file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings />
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="FDServer.FuelServerService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                    contract="FDServer.IFuelServerService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/FDServer/FuelServerService/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Client configuration file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IFuelServerService" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/FDServer/FuelServerService/"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IFuelServerService"
          contract="IFuelServerService" name="WSHttpBinding_IFuelServerService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score -1):

This msdn thread has some answer and example:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/271b1816-173c-4c76-a4c4-fd9fda4b5e91/how-to-disable-wcf-security?forum=wcf